# Lua's string.find won't find pattern

Tags: string, file, lua, find, lua-5.1

I'm currently working on a program for my webpage in Lua 5.1 and got stuck in some strange stuff.

```
file=io.open("articles/" .. string.sub(string,1) .. "_1250.html")
fContent=file:read("*a")

nic,start=string.find(fContent,"<h1 style='text-align: center;'>")
print(fContent)
print(nic,start)
len=string.find(fContent,"</h1>",start)
name=string.sub(fContent,start+1,len-1)
```

returns

```
(...blah blah blah boring file(fContent)....)

     <h1 style='text-align: center;'>Article name</h1>
     <i id='desc'>Article description</i>

</div>
nil     nil
```

I also tried to find:

```
[[<h1 style='text-align: center;'>]]
```

or

```
"h1 style='text-align: center;'"
```

and it didn't work (returns `nil`)...

Comment: `"<h1 style='text%-align: center;'>"` worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `-` in `text-align` within your string.find function.

```
nic,start=string.find(fContent,"<h1 style='text%-align: center;'>")
```

will do it.

The reason why is because `-` is a special character. You can learn more about special characters here:

[Programming in Lua: Patterns](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)

Comment: could also do `fContent:find` instead of `string.find(fContent, `